# applied cordova universal links plugin in my app but when I open website on browser, the app cannot open automatically

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, android-deep-link

I cannot open my app by browsing my website with Cordova Universal Links Plugin

I have an app that apply Cordova Universal Links Plugin, so that when I open my website, it will direct to my app.

I follow every instruction and the app can be launched by using `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://myhost.com/news/" com.example.ul`

I have also added `<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://mypackage/https/<host><path>" />` which cannot be wrong as plugin generates those tags.

But nothing happen when I browse my website.

How can I solve this?

Comment: any luck figuring this out?

Comment: still not...no clue at all, it didn't show any error .

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this deep linking solution does not work in emulators.
So, Try again using an actual Android/iOS device.

The second point is when you go to your Google Play Console deep link section you should be able to see your universal link domain without any errors as the first domain in this image.

[image: Google Play Console Deep Link section]